# Is it possible to have repeatable objects in a object by using many to many relationship

Tags: strapi

**My collections in strapi**

- Orders
- Items

**My goal**

- Collection Items

  - beer
  - water
  - sprite
- example of a order

  - 3 beer
  - 2 water
  - 2 sprite

**My situation**

My solution was to use many to many relations between collections orders and items.
So when i create a order like the example from above, i got the following result:

- order

  - 1 beer
  - 1 water
  - 1 sprite

It seems that strapi can't handle repeatable (same id) items in a collection. Am i doing something wrong or is there just no way to make this kind of relations between collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I suggest you use a component (repeatable) to do that.

In the Content Type Builder create a new component.
With a number field and a relation field with your products.

In your Order Content Type you add a component field, select the repeatable option and use the component you just created.

With that, in your Orders, you will be able to add a new item, specify which item and the numbers of items (with the interfere field)